# Load image to program (to work with jar)

Tags: java, image, resources

I'd like to load an image to my program, but in away that my runnable jar will also be able to do so.
So `new ImageIcon(URL);` to `JLabel` doesn't really work.

All my java files are in src folder, in `core` package. I'd like to put my picture to src folder, but inside `images` package.

Is that possible, or do I have to put my image to specific location inside my project?

And what would be a way to load image into my program so it works inside a runnable jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I usually embed imagery inside Java Jar files is I have a package in my `src` folder that contains all of my image files plus a single class called `Resource`.  The class code is similar to the following:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Resource{
    public static BufferedImage loadImage(String imageFileName){
        URL url = Resource.class.getResource(imageFileName);
        if(url == null) return null;

        try {
            return ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static ImageIcon loadIcon(String imageFileName){
        BufferedImage i = loadImage(imageFileName);
        if(i == null) return null;
        return new ImageIcon(i);
    }
}
```

Provided the `Resource` class and all of your image files reside in the same package, all you have to do is create a new `JLabel` with the `ImageIcon` returned by calling `loadIcon([simple filename])`.  This will work regardless of whether you're running in an IDE or from a Jar file.