# Java Distribution Code vs Development Code

Tags: java, build, environment

I have an application developed in Java that's almost ready for distribution.  However, I have a problem switching from my development env to publishing env, and back to development.  For instance, in Eclipse, if I just want to do a test run via the run button, I have to change the code so my JMenuItems show up.

In my development environment I had the following that worked well:

```
JMenuItem[] appItems = new JMenuItem[2];
appItems[0] = new JMenu("New");
appItems[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon(../POS_System/images/new_icon_sm.png")));
```

But, as I near deployment, to get this to work in the deployable JAR, I need to alter the code:

```
JMenuItem[] appItems = new JMenuItem[2];
appItems[0] = new JMenu("New");
appItems[0].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/new_icon_sm.png")));
```

This is order to reach into the JAR and get the appropriate image.

I have a lot of these JMenuItems.  I'd really like to be able to test the app via the run button in Eclipse, as well as create a JAR without changing the code.

Is there a simple way to do this?  I thought the getResource method would still allow me to use the JMenus, JMenuItems etc, but they aren't available when I run the program from Eclipse.  It seems silly that I would have to keep switching back and forth.

I appreciate any help here.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290265/load-image-to-program-to-work-with-jar

See my answer to that question for an example of how to load images in development and production environments with exactly the same code.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ben.  I must say, though, that this technique seems kind of a "kludge".  I'd also prefer to have my file system organized so the images are not in the src folder where I keep java packages.  Anyone else have any ideas?  If I must use this technique I will, but would prefer not to.

Comment: The only other option I'm aware of would be to keep an image folder somewhere relative to the present working directory.  So in your IDE, it would be [project folder]/images, and subsequently [installation folder]/images.  But to me, this seems like more of a kludge than keeping all immutable imagery in the jar, hidden from the end-user.

Comment: Hi Ben.  I've been trying to get this to work for a while now and it seems that Resource.java always returns null for loadImage(string).  I have JMenuItem[] newItems = new JMenuItem[5]; and then newItems[0] = new JMenuItem("Calculator", Resource.loadIcon("calculator_icon_sm.png"));  This should be the correct way to use this right?

Comment: Also, I believe I've followed your instructions correctly by putting the Resource.java in my pos.image package along with all the other images.  I've traced the code myself and I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Yes, that's correct - if you use the code in my example, the argument of "loadImage()" should be a path relative to the folder that contains Resource.java.  Also, make sure that your paths are case-sensitive (differences in case will cause problems even when running in Windows).

Comment: Thanks.  Ya I did all of that.  What I ended up doing is just making the ant build do all the work.  I figure that since I need it for publishing I may as well just make that the working build.  So the run button in eclipse doesn't work, but I guess that's really not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to move your images into the src/ folder as you have suggested, then in Eclipse, you should update your Eclipse configuration under the Project Prooperties -> Java Build Path and add an additional source folder, this one pointing to where you keep your images.  I believe this will fix it.